# Write an XML with multiple elements which in turn contains multiple elements

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Here I have an XML file with multiple students and multiple teachers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<users>
  <students>
    <student id="student1">
      <name>Alan</name>
      <age>11</age>
      <dob>01/01/2001</dob>
      <grade>A+</grade>
    </student>
    <student id="student2">
      <name>Bob</name>
      <age>22</age>
      <dob>02/02/2002</dob>
      <grade>A</grade>
    </student>
  </students>

  <teachers>
    <teacher id="teacher3">
      <name>David</name>
      <age>33</age>
      <dob>03/03/2003</dob>
      <subject>Maths</subject>
    </teacher>
    <teacher id="teacher4">
      <name>Ellen</name>
      <age>44</age>
      <dob>04/04/2004</dob>
      <subject>English</subject>
    </teacher>
  </teachers>
</users>
```

I have a Java application that reads this file with no problem. However, in terms of writing it, its a confusing mess. It has something to do with the fact that the application behaves as expected when reading and writing the name/age/dob, but the moment I try and write grade/subject, it looses control.

I test this by printing the name for each item within the list; and it prints as expected:

- Alan
- Bob
- David
- Ellen

I test this again by printing the age for each item within the list as well; and again, it prints as expected:

- Allan
- 11
- Bob
- 22
- David
- 33
- Ellen
- 44

However this time, I try and print the subject instead:

- Allan
- Maths
- Bob
- English
- David

It prints the subjects under the students and breaks after printing the first teacher, and I'm trying to understand why. So for my final test, I decided to print all of the elements that are at index 0, including both grade and subject to see what happens:

- Alan
- 11
- 01/01/2001
- A+
- Maths

Subject should be at index 2, not 0, so why is it doing this? Why is the system reading and writing correctly up until this exact point? Just encase, here is my XSD that is used to validate the XML before reading it.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
  <xs:element name="users">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="students" minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
    <xs:element ref="teachers" minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="students">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="student" minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="student">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="name" minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
        <xs:element ref="age" minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
        <xs:element ref="dob" minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
    <xs:element ref="grade" minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="teachers">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="teacher" minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="teacher">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="name" minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
        <xs:element ref="age" minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
        <xs:element ref="dob" minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
    <xs:element ref="subject" minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="name" type='xs:string'/>
  <xs:element name="age" type='xs:string'/>
  <xs:element name="dob" type='xs:string'/>
  <xs:element name="grade" type='xs:string'/>
  <xs:element name="subject" type='xs:string'/>
</xs:schema>
```

---

Apologies, I forgot to include the following coding. Here is the coding that writes the new data into the XML file:

```
void updateXML(int index, String fields[]) {

  try {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(fileName));

    doc.getElementsByTagName("name").item(index).setTextContent(fields[0]);
    doc.getElementsByTagName("age").item(index).setTextContent(fields[1]);
    doc.getElementsByTagName("dob").item(index).setTextContent(fields[2]);

    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(fileName));

    transformer.transform(source, result);

  } catch (Exception error) {

    error.getMessage();
  }
}
```

At the moment it works, it saves the data correctly. But grade/subject is not included because of the issue I am having.

---

This is the class that creates the objects:

```
class Model extends DefaultHandler {

String          fileName;
ArrayList<User> listOfUsers;
Student         student;
Teacher         teacher;

boolean blnStudent  = false;
boolean blnTeacher  = false;
boolean blnName     = false;
boolean blnAge      = false;
boolean blnDOB      = false;
boolean blnGrade    = false;
boolean blnSubject  = false;

Model() {

    fileName    = "school.xml";
    listOfUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
}

ArrayList<User> getListOfUsers() {

    if (validateXML() == true) {

        try {

            SAXParserFactory factory    = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser            = factory.newSAXParser();

            parser.parse(new File(fileName), this);

        } catch (Exception error) {

            error.getMessage();
        }
    }

    return listOfUsers;
}

boolean validateXML() {

    try {

        SchemaFactory factory   = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        Schema schema           = factory.newSchema(new File("school.xsd"));
        Validator validator     = schema.newValidator();
        Source source           = new StreamSource(new File(fileName));

        validator.validate(source);
        return true;

    } catch (Exception error) {

        error.getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String tagName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("student")) {

        student     = new Student(attributes.getValue("id"));
        blnStudent  = true;

    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("teacher")) {

        teacher     = new Teacher(attributes.getValue("id"));
        blnTeacher  = true;

    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {

        blnName = true;

    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("age")) {

        blnAge = true;

    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("dob")) {

        blnDOB = true;

    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("grade")) {

        blnGrade = true;

    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("subject")) {

        blnSubject = true;
    }
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String tagName) throws SAXException {

    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("student")) {

        listOfUsers.add(student);

    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("teacher")) {

        listOfUsers.add(teacher);
    }
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    if (blnStudent) {

        if (blnName) {

            student.setName(new String(ch, start, length));
            blnName = false;

        } else if (blnAge) {

            student.setAge(new String(ch, start, length));
            blnAge = false;

        } else if (blnDOB) {

            student.setDOB(new String(ch, start, length));
            blnDOB = false;

        } else if (blnGrade) {

            student.setGrade(new String(ch, start, length));
            blnGrade    = false;
            blnStudent  = false;
        }

    } else if (blnTeacher) {

        if (blnName) {

            teacher.setName(new String(ch, start, length));
            blnName = false;

        } else if (blnAge) {

            teacher.setAge(new String(ch, start, length));
            blnAge = false;

        } else if (blnDOB) {

            teacher.setDOB(new String(ch, start, length));
            blnDOB = false;

        } else if (blnSubject) {

            teacher.setSubject(new String(ch, start, length));
            blnSubject = false;
            blnTeacher = false;
        }
    }
}

void updateXML(int index, String fields[]) {

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory   = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder          = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc                        = docBuilder.parse(new File(fileName));

        doc.getElementsByTagName("name")    .item(index).setTextContent(fields[0]);
        doc.getElementsByTagName("age")     .item(index).setTextContent(fields[1]);
        doc.getElementsByTagName("dob")     .item(index).setTextContent(fields[2]);
        // IF STUDENT
        doc.getElementsByTagName("grade")   .item(index).setTextContent(fields[3]);
        // ELSE TEACHER

        TransformerFactory factory  = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer     = factory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source            = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result         = new StreamResult(new File(fileName));

        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (Exception error) {

        error.getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: All we know is that "Java" did this to you.

Comment: Computers only do what you tell them to do. That is known as a program. So far, we now know your problem, but not what you told the computer to do (aka program). Give us your code to inspect.

Comment: Sorry about that; I have included the code that updates the XML.

Comment: You have stated a problem with subjects and grades, and yet you have shown us no code that deals with subjects or grades. You say there is a problem with printing values from the XML, and yet you have shown us no code that prints values from the XML. Are we being punk'd?

Comment: Sorry I'm not punking you or trying too. I assumed that what I provided was enough; however I will show you how these objects are created.

Comment: Sorry about that. Is what I included enough to work with now?

Comment: Thank you. I think I see the problem now. You're setting your `boolean` flag variables to `false` when `characters()` is called, but `characters()` is not guaranteed to provide all of a node's content in one call, so the logic is getting completely messed up. You need to build up the value incrementally and set your flags to `false` in `endElement()`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883296/sax-parser-ignores-text-because-of-a-br-tag/22890411#22890411

Comment: I think I understand what the problem is, I just haven't found a solution for it yet. When I say `doc.getElementsByTagName("subject").item(1).getTextContent();` I'm not saying `get the first TEACHER'S subject value` what I'm saying is `get the first SUBJECT value`. I think that's why the subject's index value was wrong, the index isn't determined by how many teachers/students are made, its determined by how many subjects themselves are made. If that's the case, then I got to figure out how to set the index value dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the elements are not tide to the users themselves; they can only be called by the number of which they have been created too. For example, when I'm setting a user's name:

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).setTextContent("Alan Zero");
```

I am not asking the system to `set the FIRST USER'S name value`, what I am asking the system to do is `set the FIRST NAME value`. So as long as each user has the exact same number of fields created, this would not be a problem, since each field would automatically be assigned to their respective user. For example:

- (0) Alan Zero
- (1) Bob One
- (2) Chris Two

And if they each had grades:

- (0) A
- (1) B
- (2) C

However in my example, some users can have grade values, whiles some users can have subject values. As a result, the index values becomes inconsistent. For example:

- (0) (Student) Alan Zero
- (1) (Teacher) Bob One
- (2) (Student) Chris Two

Thus, the grade/subject values would be indexed like so:

- (0) A
- (1) B

And:

- (0) Maths

In order to correct this, I would need to find a way to tie each element respectively. Thank you everyone for your prompt replies.